# Ceiling fan installation box

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

[image]

How do I tell if this is a box for a ceiling fan? This is a 25 foot ceiling. No idea if this is ceiling fan friendly or not.

[image]

Comment: Ceiling fan boxes will be stamped with the listing and weight rating. Hard to tell from the photo even though it is a well focused shot. I would expect to see some screws on the back to a cross brace if it it was designed and installed for a fan.

Comment: Can you get a close-up of the insides of the box?

Comment: Added a closer look with wires moved out the way.

Comment: @Judy -- can you post what the stamped text on the back of the box says?

Comment: @Judy There's a couple things you want to look out for. The box being fan rated isn't as important as the bar hanger that the box is attached to being rated to hold a fan. Just about every junction box made of metal will hold your standard fan up, and since that has what seems to be #10 screws, it's probably safe to say the box itself isn't going to be an issue. If that was my house, or I was doing this job, I would remove that box (by taking out the two screws near the center) and inspect the bar and how it's mounted. It's common to find bar hangers installed with just staples....

Comment: @Judy Also, you can get a [new fan-rated no-access bar hanger](http://www.homedepot.com/p/15-5-cu-in-Retrofit-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Brace-0110000/204845572) at your local home depot for less than $15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the screw hole on the bottom, left side of the picture (labelled "fan") the box seems capable of holding a fan.

Likewise, seeing two nylock nuts holding the box in is also a pretty good indication of a strong mount on the back side of this box.

I would say it is probably safe to proceed mounting a fan in this box.

Comment: It's amazing how many times I looked at the photo and never saw the screw labeled "fan"... Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad. I downloaded the picture and was trying to do some photoediting to read the text in the back of the box... It was when I rotated it that I noticed that :)